# Django 1.11.7 --> 2.0 --> 2.2 migration - errors on runserver and Wall check

Tags: django, migration, django-2.2

I am doing migration from Django 1.11.7 --> 2.0 --> 2.2
I am running though some errors and needs some help on how to solve this.

Here are the error output
https://gist.github.com/axilaris/2088f3dfc281a2be6f9461d6577ca8dd

here are some excerpts of the error outout

```
$python -Wall manage.py check --settings=railercom.settings.local
....


/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py:426: ImportWarning: Not importing directory /Users/axil/Documents/project/unrealpower/unrealpower_upgrade_v2/unrealpowerenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ruamel: missing __init__
...
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: ImportWarning: can't resolve package from __spec__ or __package__, falling back on __name__ and __path__
      return f(*args, **kwds)
    System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
```

and

```
$python manage.py runserver --settings=unrealpower.settings.local
....
AttributeError: cffi library '_constant_time' has no function, constant or global variable named '__spec__'
.....

  File "/Users/megasap/Documents/project/railerdotcom/railerdotcom_upgrade_v2/railerdotcomenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 124, in iter_modules_and_files
    if getattr(module, '__spec__', None) is None:
SystemError: <built-in function getattr> returned a result with an error set
```

Comment: The errors from the github link you posted seem to be due to missing `__init__.py` files in your packages.  I'd check and make sure that there is an `__init__` file in *every* directory in your project.  That certainly won't solve all of these errors, but it will help narrow the scope of your problem.

Comment: thanks. any idea what is this _bootstrap_external.py ? I have pip uninstall billiard, matplotlib, django-bootstrap3, django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker-2. I still dont get it, _bootstrap_external error still appears

Comment: After a [google search](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py), it appears to be a part of cython.  I don't know much about cython or this issue though.

Comment: @Axil: did you try to reinstall `ruamel` library? And libcffi also (`brew reinstall libffi`)?

Comment: i uninstall and install - ruamel.yaml==0.16.5
ruamel.yaml.clib==0.1.2. but the reinstall version is the same. im not sure what libffi, havent tried to reinstall that yet since i dont want to break my original working environment if its going to reinstall the whole environment rather than the virtual environment.

Answer (score -1):

Create an empty `__init__.py` file in every directory of your project.